# Created a dynamic form for registration and saved all data to firebase.How to retrieve all views back to users

Tags: android, firebase, dynamic, layout-inflater

I have created dynamic form using layout inflater.After creating dynamic form it would be saved in firebase database, now when user opens the app it should fetch those views which were created and saved in database. 
Example:- I create 2 edittext, 1 spinner and 1 datepicker, after uploading all data to database how can i fetch the same views to my user.Can anyone suggest me a idea.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have created an activity (admin part)  by which u can add dynamic number of views like edittext, textview and spinners which will be saved in database. Now to user part, how can i create and retrieve those views again in users activity.